# Using nested for loops to produce multiple lines of String output

Tags: java

I am learning Java for myself and have following problem:

> Task: Write (explicitly) nested `for` loops to produce the following output:
>
> ```
>     5
>   5 5
> 5 5 5
>   5 5
>     5
> ```

My idea:

```
public class Exercises {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        for (int line = 1; line <= 3; line++) {
            for (int i = 1; i<= -2*line+6; i++){
            System.out.print(" ");
            }   
            System.out.println("5");
        }
        for ( int line = 4; line <= 5; line ++){
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2*line-6; i++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("5");
        }
    }
}
```

My output:

```
    5
  5
5
  5
    5
```

I don't know how to get nested loops there.  Can you give me not the answer, but some tips?

Comment: Did you try debugging the issue?

Comment: I dont know how to use debugging (in Eclipse) but I will try it now. Btw I dont understand what the benefit of debugging would be here...

Comment: Look it up on google. There is a logical error there. Debugging should help you in fixing this issue. :)

Comment: The problem which I'm seeing is that you're printing the spaces first, then printing "5". However, after printing one "5" for that line, you move onto the next line immediately without looking to see if you need to print more "5"s. A way to do this is likely such as checking the line number you're on (with the help of a counter of sorts), and seeing how many "5"s you need to print. If there are more, then you can loop until it's completed. Could look into while loops for this.

Of course, this isn't the best method to solve this question, but likely similar to what you're working on now.

Comment: And with the point of Eclipse debugging, you'll find the "step" functions very useful with suitable breakpoints set (such as at the loop). I used [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) for my learning of Eclipse debugging.

Comment: Try to play with **print** insteted of **println**

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
/**
 *
 * @author Adil
 */
public class Exercises {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for(int s = 4; s > i; s--) {
                // add spacing
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                //display/add star
                System.out.print("5");
            }
            // add new line
            System.out.println("");
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            for (int s = 1; s < i; s++) {
                // add spacing
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 4; j > i; j--) {
                //display/add star
                System.out.print("5");
            }
            // add new line
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
}
```

It will produce the following output:

```
  5
 55
555
 55
  5
```

Comment: Your solution is missing the spaces between the "5"s in line 2-4, and the comments should be "5" and not "star".

Comment: Yeah and I still dont know how to solve this, but still thank you all :)

Comment: Your program's output doesn't quite match the spec.  In addition to the missing spaces Foleosy pointed out, it also produces a line of nothing _but_ spaces before printing the triangle.  (I can't seem to convince Markdown to display a line of spaces at the start of a code block.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution give below:

```
public class Exercises {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int noOfColumns = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // Enter no of 5's in last
                                                        // column
        int noOfRows = noOfColumns;
        int index = noOfColumns;
        int mid = noOfRows / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++) {
            if (i <= mid) {
                index = index - 2;
            } else {
                index = index + 2;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < noOfColumns; j++) {
                if (j % 2 == 0 && j >= index) {
                    System.out.print("5");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

            } // End of inner loop

            System.out.println("");
        } // End of outer loop

    }

}
```